# Understanding the assignment operator - javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript my understanding of the assignment operator is that it is the `=` sign.
    var x = 120

but if you then wanted to do a for loop using this variable, you would normally shorten it for example:

```
for (x = 120; x < 140; x++);
```

so in between the paranthesis,it appears that the < symbol is also an assignment operator, as it states it is less than 140 and should be increased to 140.
Could someone explain more clarity on this or point me in the right direction, as most things i find shows this rightfully as the less than operator.

Comment: `function myfunction (i=1; i < thisVar; i++)` is a syntax error, so we can't explain the code as it doesn't make sense.

Comment: `<` is never an assignment operator.

Comment: `<` is not an assignment operator, but a [comparison (specifically, *relational*) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: Are you confusing function calls with a `for` loop here?

Comment: `(i=1; i < thisVar; i++)` is typically used in a `for` loop (and a syntax error in a function call/declaration), there it isn't a assignment but a check if `i` is still less than `thisVar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `function myfunction (i=1; i < thisVar; i++)` is a syntax error. We can't explain how that code works because it doesn't.

You may be thinking of the `for` loop:

```
for (i=1; i < thisVar; i++) {
}
```

The `for` loop has three expressions within its `()` that are separated with `;`:

1. An initialization (`i=1` in your case) that occurs at the very beginning, before the first test (see #2)
2. A test (`i < thisVar` in your case) that is performed prior to each iteration of the loop and determines whether the loop ends
3. An update (`i++` in your case) that occurs after each loop iteration, before the test

This is intrinsic to how `for` loops work, and is not general-purpose; you can't just do that within `()` anywhere you like, it has to be on a `for` loop.

The `<` in that, as you can see above, is part of the *test* — a condition that must be true for the loop to continue. It's not an assignment. It's a relational operator comparing `i` with `thisVar` to determine whether `i` is less than `thisVar`.